# How to avoid creating values from loops

Tags: r

I am a R learner. I don't know how to search this question so I post it here. Please help me to find the correct answer/ or point me to the correct link. Thanks.

When using while loop, for loop, or functions/loops. The r program will create temporary values. I don't know how to create local values only (inside loops only). So now I have to use rm() to remove them one by one.

I tried "=" and "<-" in while loop, but they both create global values. Any suggestions?

### Edited

I take Justin's code and continue my questions:

---

### 1

"for" loop is going to create temporary values/data.frames, no matter you use "<-" or "=". Am I correct?

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    print(i)
}
print(i)
```

---

### 2

I changed the second one a little. It seems like in a function, no matter "<-" or "=", it 
wouldn't create any temporary values. Correct?

```
f <- function(i=1:10) {
  gogo = i # or gogo <- i
  return(gogo)
}
f()
```

Comment: Use functions (and avoid loops if possible).

Comment: Can you provide a simple example (with reproducible code) that illustrates your question? Otherwise it will be hard for anyone to help.

Comment: You are correct for both questions.  In the future, please don't edit your question after the fact to add questions though, instead ask a new one.  FWIW, you can often consider `=` and `<-` to be equivalent (but definitely not always, e.g.  `f(i <- 1:5)`

Answer (score 1):

Many languages behave this way.  Where your iterator variable is still in the environment after your loop:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    print(i)
}
print(i)
```

To avoid this, you need to execute the code in a different environment.  The simplest way to do that is to write functions:

```
f <- function(i=1:10) {
    print(i)
}
f()
print(i)
```

The last `print(i)` will error since `i` wasn't created in your global environment but rather inside the scope of the function.  Additionally, R has some handy helper functions to facilitate something similar to looping.  They are the `apply` family of functions where my favorite starting point is `sapply`.

```
sapply(1:10, print)
```

or

```
f <- function(i) {
    print(i)
}
sapply(1:10, f)
print(i)
```